# C Inline ASM: passing integers to a register

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to make a simple kernel but I'm stucked on a cursor screen movement.
My function, for move the cursor, is written in Assembly, but the rest of the kernel is in C, so I have to make a C function for call that function. And that's the C function:

```
void setCursor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    asm("mov (%0), %%bl" :: "r" (y) : "%bl");
    asm("mov (%0), %%bh" :: "r" (x) : "%bh");
    asm("call set_cursor");
}
```

In this function, I try to move the var `unsigned int x` to register `bh` and the other, `unsigned int y`, to register `bl`, and then call the function to move the cursor.

The problem is when I call this function, the cursor disappear from the screen. I think the values `x` and `y` and registers values `bl` and `bh` are not the same. For give you an idea of that clue, I tested to pass values directly in the asm directive and it works:

```
void setCursor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    asm("mov $1, %bl");
    asm("mov $2, %bh");
    asm("call set_cursor");
}
```

Any help is welcome. And thanks in advance. :D

**Assembly output from compiler**
Ubuntu 12.04 64bit compiling in 32bit

```
setCursor:
.LFB12:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    pushl   %ebx
    .cfi_offset 3, -12
#APP
# 131 "./kernel/screen.c" 1
    mov (%eax), %bl
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
#APP
# 132 "./kernel/screen.c" 1
    mov (%eax), %bh
# 0 "" 2
# 133 "./kernel/screen.c" 1
    call set_cursor
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    popl    %ebx
    .cfi_restore 3
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    .cfi_restore 5
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the asm set_cursor function to use the CDECL calling convention and you can avoid the inline asm entirely. Just use `extern void set_cursor(int x, int y)` and you can call it like any other C function. I use this for all asm in my own "kernel" (LGDT/IDT/etc). The only exception being setting cr3 for paging, since it's so simple.

Assuming Intel syntax, you could add:

```
set_cursor:
   mov     ecx, [esp + 4] # x in ecx (args are pushed right to left)
   mov     edx, [esp + 8] # y in edx

   push    ebx            # ebx has to be preserved in CDECL

   mov     bh, cl
   mov     bl, dl

   # Your original code...

   pop     ebx
   ret
```

Comment: thanks :D Al least if I try printing the number to the screen, it prints 1, or the number I passed in the function. I will try writing the asm function with CDECL calling convetion

Comment: It makes things a lot easier. :) Good luck with your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you seem to be accessing the wrong variable with `%0`, since the position 0 of variables has been skipped, and usualy, you must set `=` to the destination variable.

```
asm("mov (%1), %%bh" : : "r" (x) : "=bh");
                       |
                    %0 skipped
```

Also you can try to change the way you access registers:

```
register unsigned int *p0 asm ("r0") = x;
```

Read more [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: The numbers correspond only to the ordinal of the argument. You can have arbitrarily many arguments to an asm (well as many as you have registers for), %0 just refers the first one in the list.